# django ajax post empty data

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to post data to a django view using ajax. I have no errors just there is no data returned.
Here is my javascript ajax:

```
 function PostGoal(){
    console.log('POSTGOAL!!!')
    data_s = {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
            'goal': { 'name':'gg','box':'sasa' }
        }

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",//"{% url 'home' %}",//"/",//"{% url 'home' %}",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        //data: JSON.stringify(data_s),
        data: {'QQww': "1"},
        //dataType: 'json',//expected type of response
        success: function (data) {
          console.log('aa'+JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        error: function(xhr,errmsg,err){
            console.log('err: '+JSON.stringify(err)+' msg:'+errmsg)
        }
    });
}
```

here is my view function:

```
def analyzer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    post_data = request.POST
    print(post_data)
    print ('  ajax:',request.is_ajax())
```

The boolean request.is_ajax() is ajax is always False request.data or request.POST.data do not exist and same for GET: request.GET is empty. However I can see in the log in the terminal :

```
  [22/Mar/2018 22:15:26] "GET /?QQww=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 9746
```

so essentially the data are parsed in the url? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should investigate why it's being seen as a GET when you specify POST.

Comment: thing is also request.GET is empty so the data is not even in GET

Answer (score 1):

I read in some other posts that 'method' was the right field to specify the call. For some reason, the parameter 'method' is NOT working and the correct field is 'type':

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' }
    });
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",//"{% url 'home' %}",//"/",//"{% url 'home' %}",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    //data: JSON.stringify(data_s),
    data: {'QQww': "1"},
    //dataType: 'json',//expected type of response
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('aa'+JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    error: function(xhr,errmsg,err){
        console.log('err: '+JSON.stringify(err)+' msg:'+errmsg)
    }
});
```

The html button also needs to be of type 'button' not 'submit':

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="yesbtn" name="yesbtn" value="yesbtn" onclick="PostGoal();">Yes &raquo;</button>
```

I also added the ajax setup for the csrf token to correct the error:

```
  'Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /'
```

I hope it helps.